# Bash script to connect to *.ovpn randomly

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to edit the following bash script to connect to `vpn` randomly from the list of `.ovpn` files inside the directory.

I've downloaded the following `ovpn` files from `nordvpn`

[List of NordVPN OVPN config](https://downloads.nordcdn.com/configs/archives/servers/ovpn.zip)

and here's the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
RANGE=200 #here will be total number of ovpn config files inside tcp directory.

number=$RANDOM
let "number %= $RANGE"
fname="$*.nordvpn.com.tcp.ovpn"
openvpn "$fname"
```

My issue is how to write this part correctly `fname="$*.nordvpn.com.tcp.ovpn"`

which will let the script to select one ovpn randomly and connect to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -- *.nordvpn.com.tcp.ovpn
shift $(( RANDOM % $# ))
openvpn "$1"
```

This sets the positional parameters to the list of VPN files then shifts off a random number of them (zero through N-1), leaving a "random" VPN file as parameter #1, which is then used.

(There's no error-checking for the existence of VPN files)