# How to import multiple OpenVPN files to network manager?

Tags: kali-linux, networkmanager, openvpn, vpn

I just subscribed for `ProtonVPN`, and they provided me with a bunch of `ovpn` 
servers list.

I downloaded all servers `ovpn` confg files and now I have like 100 of them in a folder in my system.

I managed to import and connect via `VPN` using gnome network manager `I'm on Kali`. but I have to manually install and enter credential each `ovpn` config file to have them all in my net man.
Any idea on how to speed up this process? Scripts welcome :)

Comment: Seems to be a recent trend: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/519818/117549

Comment: @Kodeeo are you still looking for help?

Comment: Yes I am still looking for help, i just added some vpns manually trough the graphical procedure by now